# how to Use @JsonIgnore according to the rest request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

NOTE : ***Different concepts are not included in order to focus on the problem. It is normally incorrect to use Entity in API requests. In this example, Entities were used in the API architecture to focus only on the problem.***

I was making some examples with JPA.

I had to use `@JsonIgnore` when I was establishing a relationship. When I didn't use JsonIgnore, it went into an infinite loop and gave a serialization error.  Then I solved my problem by adding `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the relevant field.

However, for example, when I want to bring all the users using branch number 1 and branch number 1, I cannot return the list because it marks it with `@JsonIgnore`. Can I filter `@JsonIgnore` markup according to rest requests?

If a POST request comes, `@JsonIgnore` should work, but if a GET request comes, `@JsonIgnore` should be inactive.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private double balance;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "branchCode")
    private Branch branch;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Branch {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Integer branchCode;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

Add brach ( POST METHOD )

---

[image: add branch]

---

Get Account ( POST METHOD )

[image: add account]

---

Get Account info ( GET METHOD )

[image: get account]

---

Get Branch ( GET METHOD )

[image: get branch]

---

Comment: Do not use Entiteis in your API. It is very bad architecture. Read about 3tier architecture

Comment: hey thank you for comment,I know you need to use DTO in API usage. This is just an example. Example for problem solving purposes. :)

Comment: Use different models. Take a look at CQRS [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)

Comment: Dear friends, we are not discussing architecture right now :) Can I use the @JsonIgnore object conditionally? This is what I wonder and want to ask. Thank you.

Comment: *Can I use the @JsonIgnore object conditionally* No you can't

Comment: So what can I do to solve this problem? :) Is writing QUERY as custom the right solution?

Comment: We told you the right solution. But as you answered: *we are not discussing architecture right now*

Comment: Here's what I don't understand, when I want to send data without @JsonIgnore, I get a serialization error. Stackoverflow error. 
For this reason, I have to add JsonIgnore  How will there be a solution to this problem when I use "3tier architecture"? I don't understand this.

Comment: What @Jens is talking solves your current issue. Ref [this](https://medium.com/@st.khwu/spring-boot-hibernate-onetomany-and-manytoone-infinite-loop-7a878637a2e1) in order to understand how using DTO solves this.

Comment: @smhylc: Jackson will map all Accounts for a branch, where every branch has an acount which has branches .... If you use DTO's you have only the reference between Accounts and branches, not the branches to accounts which solves the problem

Comment: And you can have different DTOs for different endpoints. One for branch with accounts, one for account with branches.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your valuable time and sharing your valuable comments. I will try these.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add and remove annotations at runtime. Check out [this article](https://uzxmx.github.io/add-or-remove-java-annotation-at-runtime.html) on the subject. The idea here is that you would set the annotation during a POST call, and remove the annotation during a GET call.

Whether or not this will work with Jackson, or your use case, I do not know, but your question related specifically to "use the @JsonIgnore object conditionally". Whether this approach works or not is something you can determine through experimentation, and hopefully report back with your results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're persisting on using the same entity for every response , @JsonIgnore is not the best approach you should take if the responses are varying ,instead you could use @JsonView and assign every field to a specific view (a field can be assigned to multiple views) and then you can specify on top of your endpoint what view it should use in the rendering ,you should take a look at that annotation @JsonView , hope it helps.